# BACKUP DATABASE terminates abnormally

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

I'm trying to back up a database from SQL Server, but I get the following error:

> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

My code:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DogruHukuk] 
TO DISK = N'C:\backup\appDbLive\10022018_125654' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
     NAME = N'DogruHukuk-Full Database Backup', 
     SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

Comment: What kind of SQL? Is it giving you any additional error? Does it show anything in the SQL logs?

Comment: Could be permission issues to the folder

Comment: Is this on a *remote* SQL Server machine? If so: does that **directory** (`C:\backup\appDbLive`) exists **on that REMOTE server machine**??